# Magento2 Multi store configuration

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore, multidomain

I'm using Magento 2.1.0. I have configured the multi-website, multi-store,  multi-store-view. Referred [this link](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-magento-2.html) and [this link](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-and-configure-multistore-magento-2/).

Steps I did:

I have configured in the backend.

Created `new-folder` in the root.

Copied `index.php` and `.htaccess` files to the `new-folder`.

When accessed my new site like `http://example.com/mystore2`, it is not working.

How to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your store to just be placed within different "folders" their is a setting for this under:

> Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Add Store Code to Urls

Then you don't need to create new directories or anything.

Comment: It shows a warning like some functionalities like PayPal are will not work properly. It is my live domain.

Comment: It mentions 3rd party modules, I haven't tested this with Paypal yet. But I suggest either testing in on dev site and then place an order using paypal and see if everything, including proper callbacks and capturing works properly.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a store by going to  Stores > Settings > All Stores page.

Then the form will be viewed to configure new store. Configure the store and click on Save.

Then you will get a new form to create a store view.